# Why does 있는 have to be used here?

Tags: grammar

I have been self-teaching myself Korean and today I learned the adjectives this and that. I practiced making some sentences using these adjectives. These are what I came up with:

저는 이 샌드위치를 먹고 싶어요. - I want to eat this sandwich.

저는 저것 모자를 사고 싶어요. - I want to buy that hat over there.

So I asked someone for help and they gave me the correction for the second sentence. This is what they gave me:

(저는) 저기에 **있는** 모자를 사고 싶어요

So I wanted to clarify why 있는 had to be used. And also can you tell me if the first sentence is correct also?

Comment: I think your second sentence has a typo

Comment: @user17915 thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 저는 이 샌드위치를 먹고 싶어요

This sentence is correct :)

> 저는 저젓 모자를 사고 싶어요. - I want to buy that hat over there.

> (저는) 저기에 있는 모자를 사고 싶어요

First of all, "저젓" looks like a typo; I'm guessing you were thinking of "저것"(?). "저것" means "That thing", so "저것 모자" becomes "That thing hat" which isn't ideal.

있는 is required to make the sentence say "I want to buy the hat [that is] over there". 있는 fulfills the role of "that is". In English this can be left out if it's not ambiguous. In Korean, in this case, it is not left out and instead made explicit. When leaving it out:

> 저기에 모자를 사고 싶어요

it sounds like you're saying "I want to buy a hat over there". 저기 just becomes the place where you want to do the buying; you want to go over there and buy a hat, not "that specific hat over there".

Comment: Great! Also thank you for pointing out that correction with 저것. I missed that at first

Comment: @Chadee No problem! If this answered your question, please press the "Accept answer" button (the ✔️ button to the left of my answer) :)